# ASP.NET AJAX Toolkit: AutocompleteExtender: How to add suffix character to a selection?

Tags: asp.net-ajax, autocomplete, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I would like to add the delimiter after the selection after it is selected.

Say, if I select "beautiful", then it will add "beautiful; " into the textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got an answer from the ASP.NET forum:

> you can fire the Text change event of
>   the Textbox where you can add the
>   Delimiter to the Textbox. like this
>   
>   and in code file txtAutoComplete.Text
>   = txtAutoComplete.Text + ";";

[The post on the forum](http://forums.asp.net/p/1465192/3378935.aspx#3378935)